# how to add Analyzer and Tokenizer in our customfieldtype

Tags: solr, sitecore-commerce, sitecore-api

I'm trying to implement an `analyzer and tokenizer` on my created custom field type. Any ideas on how to implement it?

example:- I have created one custom field type like `wtbngramscase` in solr schema but I want to create a tokenizer and analyzer using c# code, is there any way to implement it?

```
<fieldType name="wtbngramscase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
<analyzer Type="index">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
<filters class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignorecase="true" />
<filters class="solr.EdgeNGramTokenizerFactory" mingramsize="1" maxgramsize="70" />
<filters class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
<analyzer Type="query">
<tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" />
<filters class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignorecase="true" />
<filters class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt" />
<filters class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
</analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The analyzers and tokenizers are defined in the `managed-schema` file present in the `indexname/conf` path where all the Solr cores are present (See attached image)

[image]

So to add your custom fieldtype, you may create a custom index instead of adding it to existing Sitecore indexes. Navigate to the `managed-schema` file and include your change.